# Use of "should not be" in a question

Tags: modal-verbs, questions, negation

I can't figure out which one is the correct formal one or if all the variations can be used:

- Shouldn't it be? (=?) Should not it be?
- Should it not be?
- Should it be not?

Is there a context in which they would be different/incorrect?

I could not find an answer for this among the already asked questions but if this is a duplicate please feel free to mark it as such.

Comment: Should this question not be closed? :) I'm wondering.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners stack exchange by the way! If you haven't already, you could consider taking the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) or visiting the [help centre](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: If you think I've answered your question, you can select the tick under the vote buttons to show that it is the accepted answer. I'd advise waiting a day or so though, in case someone else gives you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Shouldn't it be" is correct but informal. This is shortened from the formal "Should it not be" which is also correct.

"Should it be not" is not correct in this context.

---

A point to notice is that "Shouldn't it be this?" and "Should it be this?" have very similar meanings, despite one of them having a "not":

"Should it be this?" Is asking if the thing the speaker refers to is correct.

"Shouldn't it be this?" Is asking if the thing the speaker refers to is correct *and shows that they think the current solution is wrong*.

Comment: That's interesting... but I am still struggling to understand why would "Shouldn't it be" would be correct and "Should not it be" isn't (?) while one is simply the abbreviation of the other.

Comment: @DiegoFMedina You misunderstand. Both of those are correct. "Should it **be not**" is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

"**Shouldn't it be**" is correct for all situations other than extremely formal writing. It would be used to start a question -- "**Shouldn't it be** blue rather than orange?"

"**Should not it be**" is also correct, but sounds really awkward and old fashioned.  You would more likely use "**If it were not** blue but orange, "

"**Should it not be**" means the same thing.  It forms a start to a hypothetical with the same meaning as "**If it were not** blue, I would not like it."

"**Should it be not**" is also very archaic sounding but correct.  The meaning is a little different, though.  It also forms the start to a hypothetical like "**Should it be not** blue but orange, I would not like it"  That's very awkward sounding too.  You would more likely use "**If it were** blue rather than orange..."